# Flask Admin create user?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I am trying to build a web app that only certain users can log in to. As such while I have a registration page on my boilerplate app, I would like to disable it and use flask admin to create and manage users.

However, when I log in to the admin page certain fields like email and password are not available. How do I get these fields into the create tab on the admin menu?  See below user model.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    first_name = db.Column(db.String)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    confirmation = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    _password = db.Column(db.String)
    email_confirmation_sent_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    email_confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    last_logged_in = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    current_logged_in = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you aren't seeing an email field, since you haven't included the definition of your Users admin view, but parameters that start with an underscore (like `_password`) will be automatically hidden by flask-admin. You could explicitly include it in your User admin class:

```
class UserAdminView(BaseModelView):
    ...
    form_columns = (..., '_password', ...)
    ...
```

If regenerating or migrating your database is possible, you can also just remove the underscore from your model.

Edit:
It looks like you can also declare `ignore_hidden = False` on the user admin view.

Comment: It actually needs to be `form_columns = (..., 'password', ...)`, at least that's how it was when I tried it.

Comment: @spitfiredd The behavior is complicated a little if you have @properties defined. IIRC Flask-admin will only pick up columns defined without a leading underscore, so `ignore_hidden` won't auto-include properties; they'll only show up if you explicitly add them. (I would guess the same is true of any other non-column attributes on your model objects...).